# Calling from a Kivy object a Python event

Tags: python, events, kivy

The scenario is this: a Python Object ("Cell") creates a Kivy Button. When the Kivy Button is clicked it calls a method of the creating Python Object. Sounds simple, but I have not figured out how to accomplish this.

The current code is this

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class Cell():

    def onClick(self):
        print("Clicked")

    def getWidget(self, stringValue):
            btn = Button()
            btn.addCell(self)
            return Button(text=stringValue)

class Button(Button):

    cell = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cell = None

    def addCell(self, cell):
        self.cell = cell
        self.bind(on_press=cell.onClick)
```

This runs without errors.The Button is created and shown in the screen, but nothing happens when the it is clicked.

Comment: maybe you should use normal variable instead of `ObjectProperty()`

Comment: you return wrong value in `Cell` - you have to use `return btn`

Comment: Defining a class with the same name as its base class (`class Button(Button):`) is a bad idea. It will lead to confusion and errors.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run it but you have to use `return btn` instead of creating new widget `return Button()`

```
def getWidget(self, stringValue):
    btn = Button(text=stringValue)
    btn.addCell(self)
    return btn
    # return Button(text=stringValue)  # this creates new Button without `.addCell(self)`
```